# Flask url_for in form action

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a wtform in my html file, something like this:

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, action="/add/", method="post", extra_classes="form-horizontal", 
role="form", form_type="basic") }}
```

(I actually notice I can omit action). So this works.

Now - if I change it to

```
action="{{ url_for('add') }}"
```

, I'm ending up in this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/add/%7B%7B%20url_for('add')%20%7D%7D
```

If I just create a link in html like so:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('add') }}">link</a>
```

It does work and it gets me to /add/. I was wondering what the difference is.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
action="{{ url_for('add') }}"
```

try to assign the output of `url_for('add')` function/helper to `action`

```
action=url_for('add')
```

without `{{` and `}}`

so

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, action=url_for('add'), method="post", extra_classes="form-horizontal", role="form", form_type="basic") }}
```

Comment: It's in my template though. Anyway, I'm dumb, I put , before action in form tag.

Answer (score -1):

Remember not to put commas in the tags ;)